# php Mysql INSERT INTO: can't insert anymore

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing news and inserting it in my DB, I've build the code 3 years ago and it was working well, but yet I can't insert anymore and I don't understand why:

```
$insert=mysqli_query($co,"INSERT INTO articles VALUES('','".addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['title']))."','".time()."','".nl2br(addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['msg'])))."')") or die("insert error: ".mysqli_error());
```

where the table articles get the structure (id : int(11) auto_increment, title : text, date : int(11), msg : text)

When I try it I fell in the "insert error" message, but the mysqli_error() message is empty, so I tried a fake entry on phpmyadmin:

```
INSERT INTO articles VALUES('','testset','1396642210','FUUUUUU')
```

And I get  #1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1
(but id is auto incremented ?? :/ )

(connection and db select are ok)
I really don't understand what is happening, I was working with this request for 2/3 years and it was working...
Any ideas ?

Comment: `addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['title']))` => use prepared statement. They will be way more safe.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `1396642210`, assuming that column be integer type.  Perhaps you have upgraded MySQL and its syntax enforcement has changed (it certainly has for `GROUP BY`).

Comment: Did you recently change anything that may affect this set up? MySQL version? PHP version? Webserver version? Webserver? Doing the EXACT same thing multiple times will never yield a different result so something must have changed.

Comment: seems come from the version, thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've moved to MySQL 5.7, which has new security and data integrity check: an `INT` column can no longer hold a `STRING` value as `''`.

Use `DEFAULT` as the value, or just do not add the column in you `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO articles (title, date, msg) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO articles VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?);
```

Which is less safer if columns order is changed.

Comment: Thanks, that's true I didn't followed version changes, worked with DEFAULT, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to not put integer values in quotes, this probably applies to your `timestamp` column.

As for auto incremented columns, like your `id`, you can just leave that out of your query and add the columns you want to fill in your query:

```
INSERT INTO `articles` (`title`, `timestamp`, `msg`) VALUES ('testeset', 1396642210, 'FUUUUUU');
```